# Keeping android browser open with a service

Tags: android, browser, service

Is it possible after a user has opened the android browser to catch when the press home / `onpause()` in order to push the browser to a service or just to start the browser from a service in order to keep it open when the user presses home or locks the phone?

For instance, If the user is listening to a internet stream through the browser and they press home or lock the screen the audio will be cut off. However I would like to keep the browser open so the audio continues to play. I'm under the impression that a service would be the only way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a webview within my app and started a service when the home button (`onpause`) was pressed that enabled the broswer to continue the playback of flash while the app was in the background or the screen was locked. So while I wasn't able to use the capture the browser outside my app I was able to make an effective webview to emulate that experience.

I followed the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) to create the webview and then made a service. The piece of code (`android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`) that allowed the flash to play properly was:

> ```
> <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name" >
> ```

in the manifest. It works great! (The api must be 3.0 or greater however)

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is (and should be) impossible within Android.  All clicks and things of that nature should go through your app.  There *are* some bad situations where you *can* do this, and it's widely considered to be an Android bug.  Basically, the idea is that you shouldn't be able to control anything outside of your app.  Instead, you can only accept clicks within an app, and getting this behavior would require extending the standard Android browser with your own implementation and having users use that instead.

To see why you can't do this, consider the kinds of security implications that it would have, you could control and reroute functionality from other apps to hijack their standard user experience.  There are some situations (you can google "clickjacking" to see some) that have been possible in earlier versions of Android, but in any non malicious app, you really shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know. Do you have idea's how I could implement that conforms to proper behavior? Could I make a webview in my app and have the app be a service or is that essentially the same thing?

Comment: You're not understanding, a Service is meant to do things not associated with the UI.  A browser will inherently be associated with the UI.  Instead of having a Service, all you will do is catch the UI events and handle them properly, by handling the back button, for example.  However, note that you cannot change the behavior of the home button.  (Please don't try!)

Comment: I was able to do what I was asking with a webview and a service.